# Burnt material on the back of the oven

Tags: wiring, oven

the element on my 15 year old GE oven sparked and broke.  I ordered a new one to replace it.  Once i turned the breaker back on i tested it and it got hot.  However in making this repair i noticed on the back of the oven panel the white cotton-looking material that surrounds the wiring looks to be burnt, about the size of a small fist.  I dont know if it was caused by the element or just over time.  is this a hazard or normal?  not interested in a kitchen fire. thanks.

Comment: a picture would really help. it probably happened when the other element failed, but it's hard to say without seeing if it's an ongoing problem.

Comment: Generally that is a heat resistant material to protect the the wiring - edit the post with a picture of what yo have - so we can be sure.

Answer (score 2):

That white cotton stuff is high temperature insulation protecting the appliance skin from the high temperatures inside the oven.  Its surface will at times become colored from the heat from the oven.  This is normal.  Try to put it back in its original place when you finish the repair. P.